# React Fetch Post net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 000webhost

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs

I'm trying to save text from input to my MySQL database on 000webhost with PHP. But I get this error: **net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. TypeError: Failed to fetch**.

I tried this on React Native and it's working on React Native. I'm not familiar with React so what can be the problem?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [password1, setPassword1] = useState();
  const [copytext, setCopytext] = useState();

  async function addCopytext() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://clipperfox.000webhostapp.com/setCopytext.php",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            password: password1,
            copytext: copytext,
          }),
        }
      );
      const parsedResponse = await response.json();
      console.log(parsedResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1 className="text">Set text</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(event) => setPassword1(event.target.value)}
        placeholder="Password..."
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(event) => setCopytext(event.target.value)}
        placeholder="Text..."
      />
      <button onClick={addCopytext}>Hello</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```